# How to find element by unique xpath that has same class

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Im try to found a unique xpath for this element with same class

the first xpath that i need:

```
//*[@id="view_container"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/span/div[1]/div/div[1]/div
```

and this is the html content for it :

```
<div class="zJKIV y5MMGc sD2Hod i9xfbb" jscontroller="EcW08c" jsaction="keydown:I481le;dyRcpb:dyRcpb;click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;" jsshadow="" jsname="ornU0b" aria-labelledby="selectionc5" tabindex="0" data-value="1" aria-describedby="selectionc6" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="2">
   <div class="k5cvGe MbhUzd"></div>
   <div class="IHWLbd"></div>
   <div class="SCWude">
     <div class="t5nRo Id5V1">
       <div class="wEIpqb nQOrEb"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

and this is the second xpath that i dont need :

```
//*[@id="view_container"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/span/div[2]/div/div[1]/div
```

and this is the html :

```
<div class="zJKIV y5MMGc sD2Hod i9xfbb" jscontroller="EcW08c" jsaction="keydown:I481le;dyRcpb:dyRcpb;click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;" jsshadow="" jsname="ornU0b" aria-labelledby="selectionc7" tabindex="0" data-value="2" aria-describedby="selectionc8" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-posinset="2" aria-setsize="2">
  <div class="k5cvGe MbhUzd"></div>
  <div class="IHWLbd"></div>
  <div class="SCWude">
    <div class="t5nRo Id5V1">
      <div class="wEIpqb nQOrEb"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

as i see is the the only diffrent between 2 class is data-value so i think there is an option to selecet elmint withe class and value id but do not know how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//div[contains(@class, 'zJKIV') and @data-value='1']
```